# D3.js v4 major & minor tick lines with y-Axis zero as the centered baseline

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've achieved major and minor tick lines with D3.js v4. There was very little if none examples for achieving this.

JS:

```
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
yAxis.scale(y).ticks(48).tickSizeInner(-width).tickSizeOuter(0).tickPadding(10);

// This may need to be done after a small timeout
d3.selectAll('.axis--y1 .tick').each(function(d, i) {  
   // every 4th is 'major' without .minor class
   d3.select(this).classed('minor', (i % 4 !== 0));
});
```

CSS:

```
.tick > line {
    stroke: #bbb;
    stroke-width: 1;
}
.tick.minor > line {
    stroke: #c9c9c9;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
}
.tick.minor > text {
    display: none;
}
```

Problem is that this dataset has varied +/- range, for example from -1900 to 2300.

How can I set zero as the baseline and have other tick marks be still calculated dynamically? If not possible, such an option would be nice to have natively...

[image: non zero-centered yAxis tick marks]

Comment: Could you create a plnkr/jsfiddle/gist with the whole code available? If not, I would suggest to build the list of ticks yourself, and pass it to the axis. From my experience (mostly with v3 I admit), this is the most reliable way to get the ticks you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this was not possible but rather needed to calculate tick positions dynamically [axis.tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues). Implementation details may vary for different use cases.